# How to to add a Content Query WebPart programatically and use a SPSIteDataquery?

Tags: 2010, development, spsitedataquery

This is the current scenario.

I have a central site called: XXX.

I have many subsites called with the year name: 2012, 2011, 2010, etc.

In the central site I have a list called Beneficiaries.

In ALL year sites I have a list called Request, every one of those lists have a lookup column to the Beneficiaries list in the central site.

I need to create one webpart in the central site to show all the Requests that a Benefeciary has in all sub sites. (year sites). I wonder if the contentquery webpart will do the work because I think I will have to use spsitedataquery not use spquery.

This is the code I have so far.

```
/// <summary>
        /// Update dashboard beneficieries.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="currentUnsafeWeb"></param>
        private void UpdateDashboardBeneficiaries(SPWeb currentUnsafeWeb)
        {
            Logger.LogDebug("NLSubsidiesSiteConfigSubsidyCentralEventReceiver", "UpdateDashboardBeneficiaries(SPWeb currentUnsafeWeb)", "BEGIN");

            SPFile page = null;
            try
            {
                page = currentUnsafeWeb.GetFile("beneficiaries.aspx");
                page.CheckOut();

                //Add Content Query WebPart or something else to show all request in all yearsubsites that are related to the beneficiaries list.


                page.CheckIn(string.Empty);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (page != null) page.UndoCheckOut();
                throw;
            }

            Logger.LogDebug("NLSubsidiesSiteConfigSubsidyCentralEventReceiver", "ConfigureDashboardBeneficiaries(SPWeb currentWeb)", "END");
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you can use SPLimitedWebPartManager to add webparts programtically. The sample code for SPSiteDataQuery looks like this:
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

```
                    //Specify the fields which need to be shown.
                    query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
                                        "<FieldRef Name=\"Type\" />" +
                                       "<FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\" />" +
                                       "<FieldRef Name=\"Status\" />" +
                                       "<FieldRef Name=\"DueDate\" />";

                    query.Lists = "<Lists BaseType='0'/>";
                    query.Query = "<Where><Lt><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>0</Value></Lt></Where>";

                    // Query all Web sites in this site collection.
                    query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"SiteCollection\" />";
                    DataTable table = web.GetSiteData(query);
```

Comment: thanks, this pointed me I think in the right direction, I posted another question related to this one. if could check it please. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43629/how-can-i-link-an-xsltlistviewwebpart-and-a-contentbyquerywebpart-programaticall

Answer (score 2):

To add webpart programatically you should use [SPLimitedWebPartManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.splimitedwebpartmanager.aspx)

For an example (including ContentByQueryWebPart) see [How to create Web Part instances on pages using Features - FeatureReceiver - SPLimitedWebPartManager](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/SP2007Dev/Pages/How%20to%20create%20Web%20Part%20instances%20on%20pages%20using%20Features%20-%20FeatureReceiver%20-%20SPLimitedWebPartManager.aspx)

Comment: that part I know how to do it, the big concern here is how to set the query that the webpart should use specially becase its a query across subsites in the same site collection.

Comment: The ContentByQueryWebpart uses a SPSiteDataQuery to query all subsites of the WebUrl property. Start by configuring it in the UI, export and use those properties. You'll not be able to specify the Request(s) lists by name or url, but hopefully it has a unique list type and/or content type.

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for doing the same if given below.

```
ContentEditorWebPart wp = new ContentEditorWebPart();
//Add the webpart to the page
SPLimitedWebPartManager pageMgr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(pageURL, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
pageMgr.AddWebPart(wp, "Main", 0);

//Save the page with the changes
pageMgr.SaveChanges(wp);
```

Comment: thanks, this pointed me in a good direction, however I have another question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43629/how-can-i-link-an-xsltlistviewwebpart-and-a-contentbyquerywebpart-programaticall